# Need help, Passing variables with get_post_meta

Tags: metabox, variables

```
$slider_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'slider');
                            $slider_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'blog'); ?>

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $slider_image[0]; ?>" rel="<?php echo $slider_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo '#caption'.$slide.''; ?>" />
                            </a>
```

This is the original code for passing the value of an image, which was uploaded using the the default media uploader.

However I changed the upload method to a custom metabox, SB Uploader plugin, which uses  get_post_meta

I just don't know how to do it to get the same output. The 'blog' and 'slider' hold a size value for thumbnails.

Also this is inside a WHILE loop.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not a coder so please break it down :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found a version of Magic Fields that supports custom post types. You can find it here:

https://github.com/attitude/Magic-Fields

It looks like it is just a mod on Magic Fields to allow custom post types. And it works good so far